# Adding an image next to a table in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add an image next to a table without a newline. I have following code:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
iTextSharp.text.Font fontbold = new iTextSharp.text.Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));                                       


PdfPTable tkunde = new PdfPTable(1);
tkunde.WidthPercentage = 30;
tkunde.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;                                   

PdfPCell labkunNavn = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(navnn, fontbold));
labkunNavn.PaddingTop = 2f;
labkunNavn.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
labkunNavn.Border = 0;
tkunde.AddCell(labkunNavn);

PdfPCell labkunAdresse = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(adresse, font));
labkunAdresse.PaddingTop = 2f;
labkunAdresse.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
labkunAdresse.Border = 0;
tkunde.AddCell(labkunAdresse);

PdfPCell labkunPost = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(postnr + " " + område, font));
labkunPost.PaddingTop = 2f;
labkunPost.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
labkunPost.Border = 0;
tkunde.AddCell(labkunPost);

doc.Add(tkunde);

iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\Users\Osman\Desktop\download.jpg");
png.WidthPercentage = 10;
png.ScalePercent(50F);
png.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

doc.Add(png);
```

But it adds the image below the table as shown in the figure on following link:

http://postimg.org/image/z9rr0dk5p/4289a76a/

I want the layout to be like this instead:

http://postimg.org/image/3yae8w6q3/42ddcd80/

How do I achieve this ?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see the images when I click the links to postimg.org

Comment: Just click on the white rectangle when the page opens.

Comment: If I were to guess you're trying to treat `Element.ALIGN_RIGHT` like a CSS `float: right` which won't work. The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is just create a wrapper table around everything with two cells, one for your sub-table and one for your image.

Comment: Hi. I solved the issue. I just used the parameter 
png.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.TEXTWRAP and that's it.